# dev-c++ project1.exe has stopped working, problem accessing NULL memory?

Tags: c++, exe, dev-c++

I have two instances in my code (a binary search tree assignment) that causes Project1.exe to stop working. I have no idea what causes this error, the only thing I can guess is maybe accessing NULL memory... (I'm pretty new to dev-c++ and coding in general.)

The error goes away if I comment out my exists() function:

```
// PURPOSE: Returns true if a node with the value val exists in the tree    
// otherwise, returns false
bool BinarySearchTree::exists( BinarySearchTree::TaskItem val ) const {
    BinarySearchTree::TaskItem* cur = root;
    while(cur) {
        if((*cur) == val) return true;

        if(val.priority < cur->priority)
            cur = cur->left;
        else
            cur = cur-> right;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or if I leave this first line in my remove() function; the exe crashes if I comment it out:

```
// PURPOSE: Removes the node with the value val from the tree
// returns true if successful; returns false otherwise
bool BinarySearchTree::remove( BinarySearchTree::TaskItem val ) { // tricky
    if(exists(val) == false) return false;

    BinarySearchTree::TaskItem* cur = root;
    BinarySearchTree::TaskItem* parent = NULL;

    // iterate downwards until cur points to a node
    // that equals delete_node
    while(!((*cur) == val)) {
        // update cur and parent as you are traversing 
        // through this tree
        if(val.priority < cur->priority) {
            parent = cur;
            cur = cur->left;
        } else {
            parent = cur;
            cur = cur->right;
        }
    }

    // check that we have not reached NULL
    // if we have reached NULL, return false
    if(!cur) return false; // why tho

    // divide the code into cases
    // CASE 1: remove the leaf node
    if (!cur->left && !cur->right) {
        // decide where is cur in reference to parent
        // example: if (cur == parent->left)
        // free up cur's memory
        // set parent's pointer to NULL
        if(cur == parent->left) {
            delete cur;
            cur = NULL;
            parent->left = NULL;
        } else if(cur == parent->right) {
            delete cur;
            cur = NULL;
            parent->right = NULL;
        }

    // CASE 2: remove a node with only one child
    } else if(!cur->left) {
        if(cur == parent->left) {
            parent->left = cur->right;
            delete cur;
            cur = NULL;
        } else if(cur == parent->right) {
            parent->right = cur->right;
            delete cur;
            cur = NULL;
        }

    } else if(!cur->right) {
        if(cur == parent->left) {
            parent->left = cur->left;
            delete cur;
            cur = NULL;
        } else if(cur == parent->right) {
            parent->right = cur->left;
            delete cur;
            cur = NULL;
        }
    }

    else { // CASE 4:
        // find succ and parent of succ
        BinarySearchTree::TaskItem* parent_succ = cur;
        BinarySearchTree::TaskItem* succ = cur->right;

        while(succ->left) {
            parent_succ = succ;
            succ = succ->left;
        }

        // swap values of successor and to-delete node
        BinarySearchTree::TaskItem* temp = succ;
        succ->priority = cur->priority;
        succ->description = cur->description;
        cur->priority = temp->priority;
        cur->description = temp->description;

        parent_succ->right = succ->right;
        delete succ;
        succ = NULL;
    }

    size ++;
    return true;
}
```

If it helps (rather than also posting my insert() function) I'm 99% sure the code inserts correctly because it passes those test cases.

I would appreciate any guidance :)

Comment: `if((*cur) == val) return true;` - should this be comparing the priorities, not the whole objects?

Comment: You should be passing these items around by reference or const reference though. I'd guess the problem is something going wrong between your destructor and copy constructor (if you have one) with deleting objects that aren't copied correctly (look up the 'rule of three'). If you use references, or even pass pointers, you'll hopefully sidestep that by accidentally passing by value and making copies that you don't need or want.

Comment: *" I have no idea what causes this error"* - is what *debuggers* are literally made to help you with. If you're lucky and your program crashes (it's far, far worse when it doesn't), a debugger will take you straight to the point of doom and you can backtrace from there. I can tell you that in order to remove something from a tree, you had first be absolutely certain it was *inserted* into said-same correctly. We can't do that with the posted code because there is no [mcve] here.

Comment: @Rup I will verify about comparing priorities vs whole objects, thanks for your input!

Comment: @WhozCraig Pretty new to debugging as well unfortunately. I used the debug tool to run through our given test cases that test exist(), and all I can gather is that it skips all the asserts of exist(). If it helps, the code does pass the test cases ensuring that it inserts properly. Thanks for the response, sorry if my question isn't formatted very well.